# How to access the Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to read the data from the `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)` field of an object - in this case, it should return "Array Iterator".

[image]

This does not work

```
a.__proto__["Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)` indicates that the property is a [**symbol**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). Symbols are unique values and you can only reference such a property if you already have a reference to the symbol.

Luckily [`Symbol.toStringTag` is a *well-known symbol*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Well-known_symbols), so you can just reference it:

```
a[Symbol.toStringTag]
```

---

Here is an example where you cannot access the property directly:

```
var obj = (function() {
  // prop is a unique value
  var prop = Symbol();
  return {[prop]: 42};
}());
```

There is no way to access `obj[<the symbol>]` directly since we don't have access to `prop`. You can still iterate over the properties though.

Comment: Does not always work, example: `const d = new Date(); d[Symbol.toStringTag]` ⇒ `undefined`. It works for *some* kinds of objects but not all, for whatever reason. http://2ality.com/2015/09/well-known-symbols-es6.html#overriding-the-default-tostring-tag It seems that even though the mechanism works some classes, like `Date`, don't have such a symbol?

Comment: MDN have moved the "Well known" section into separate pages. Tried to `edit` but *«The edit queue is full at the moment»*. New link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag

Comment: Optionally: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-well-known-symbols